# StackExchange.Redis StringSet Maximum Array Size

Tags: c#, arrays, redis, stackexchange.redis

For the Redis users and for the StackExchange.Redis driver users, I am trying to initialize the cache by doing mass insertion. To do so, I have tried with a StringSet with an array of 20000 KeyValue and it's failing to time out.

My understanding is by using an array, it is doing an MSET command which should be faster than 20K SET commands. Is it? Has anyone running into this issue? How should I solve it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Failing to time out? Are you using the sync or async API?

Comment: @MarcGravell, I am trying to use the Async API. But actually, I just used redis-benchmark on SET and MSET and it seems that SET is just a little bit faster. Anyway, I got this exception `Timeout performing MSET, inst: 0, mgr: ExecuteSelect, queue: 2, qu=1, qs=1, qc=0, wr=1/1, in=0/0` when I pass  an array of 20K objects.

Comment: @MarcGravell, I followed your suggestion and it's working pretty well. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is not hugely surprising that this would time out - the bandwidth (in particular) and server time for that will be non-trivial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between multiple SET and MSET is not as big as you would think - about 10 bytes per item bandwidth, and if you use pipelining (perhaps even the FireAndForget command option): zero latency. But you could also just as easily switch to batches of (say) 100 items: again, this will have additional overhead of about 10 bytes *per batch*, which is nothing - and these batches could *also* be pipelined if you want. In either pipelined case, SE.Redis does some work to minimise packet fragmentation etc. Basically, the change I would make here is: don't sent massive batches. Send multiple smaller batches. A huge batch isn't going to give you the benefit you imagine.